# Create class instance with unknown number of attributes

Tags: python, class, instantiation

This has been taxing me for some time, so it's possible what I am trying to do is not a good thing, so I need either the solution to my problem or a recommendation of how to do it right.

I have a spreadsheet full of data which I need to transform.  The spreadsheet can have 140 or more columns, and I want to make this dynamic, so if someone changes the columns in the spreadsheet it still works.  So my spreadsheet might look like this:

<kbd>THISFIELD</kbd><kbd>THATFIELD</kbd><kbd>THIRDFIELD</kbd>
       <kbd>ABCD</kbd>          <kbd>123</kbd>           <kbd>Text</kbd>
       <kbd>EFGH</kbd>          <kbd>456</kbd>    <kbd>Other text</kbd>

etc (man, making a table here is HARD!)

This works fine, and I am guessing you know there is a but coming:

```
class MyThing:
    pass

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for attribute, value in kwargs.iteritems():
            setattr(self, attribute, value)

    def validate_my_thing(self):
        self.ATTRIBUTE = whatever I want to do with that attribute
```

If I instantiate MyThing like this:

```
new_thing = MyThing(THISFIELD="ABCD", THATFIELD=123, THIRDFIELD="Text")
```

It works perfectly.  So the problem is I want to take the attribute names from the spreadsheet (which I can do, I don't need to know how to read a spreadsheet), and populate the attribute values from the columns in the spreadsheet.  If I could instantiate the class like this:

```
new_thing = Mything({"THISFIELD": "ABCD", "THATFIELD": 123, THIRDFIELD: "TEXT"})
```

then my life would be easy.

Just to re-iterate, instantiating the class like:

```
new_thing = MyThing(THISFIELD = worksheet_cell(1,2))
```

won't work, like I said there might be 140 attributes, and I don't want the instantiation to be static, it has to be dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either change your constructor to:

```
def __init__ (self, fields):
    for attribute, value in fields.items():
        setattr(self, attribute, value)
```

Or call it with `**`:

```
new_thing = Mything(**{"THISFIELD": "ABCD", "THATFIELD": 123, THIRDFIELD: "TEXT"})
```

**Note:** If one of the keys is not a valid attribute name (e.g. `1`), the first method will fail in `setattr` while the second will fail before calling the constructor.

Comment: Thanks, works a treat, will up-vote as soon as it will let me

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
def __init__(self, fields):
    for attribute, value in fields.iteritems():
        setattr(self, attribute, value)
```

All I've done is changed `**kwargs` to `fields` in the argument list (because you're passing in an actual `dict`).

Comment: Thanks, as @Holt's answer, will up-vote as soon as it lets me.